# Autohide Taskbar at Window 10 Startup

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have the "Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode" checked but when windows restarts, the taskbar is showing. I have to click on the screen to hide the taskbar for the first time.

How can I have the taskbar automatically hidden at windows startup?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the normal Windows 10 behavior. If the Taskbar is visible after a restart, it may be indicating that there is a System [notification](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-notifications-cccdb22c-bda9-5ad5-897d-897ac67f7e39) pending, which might be hidden - check notifications.

However, you can try a third-party application such as free [Taskbar Activate](http://pmdevigne.free.fr/TaskbarActivate.html), which controls taskbar hiding. This would help with issues such as the mouse cursor accidentally causing immediate activation.